# Missing Registry entries for the Context Menu

Tags: tortoisesvn, registry, windows-vista, contextmenu

My Vista Home Basic SP2 machine misses the relevant Registry values,
described under [Page 171 of the tutorial (latest and relevent edition)](http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/tortoisesvn/Documentation/1.6.5/TortoiseSVN-1.6.5-en.pdf)

> The registry keys which hold the information on which context menus to show
>   are `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN\ContextMenuEntriesMaskLow` and
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN\ContextMenuEntriesMaskHigh`.

Answer (score 1):

i would like to make a small correction

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN\ContextMenuEntriesMaskLow` must not be a seperate key
but rather `ContextMenuEntriesMaskLow` should be a `DWORD` value in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN\` key.

So is the case for `ContextMenuEntriesMaskHigh`.

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](http://www.nabble.com/Vista-Business-no-context-menus-show-up-td22307885.html) suggests turning UAC **on** in case it is was turned off while you install.

Answer (score 0):

These registry entries are not created by TSVN. You **can** create them manually to prevent TSVN from showing certain entries. But by default, all entries are shown so the registry entry doesn't exist.
Only if you create the entry manually, TSVN will use it.